# Generic solution to compare 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

**TL;DR;**
Is there a way to compare 2 rows of the same table regardless of the table schema but ignoring a specific column?

**Long**
I've fell out of nowhere in a system maintance, and was asked to implement auditing in a few tables... 72 tables to be precise... i decided to use a Trigger on update and delete. It works fine and behaves as expected.
My problem is that the system is quite idiot, and updates rows on the table without any changes, sort of "change X for X", except for that the rows have a "rowversion" column, so, in the end "rowversion" is updated. My question is: is there a way to compare the "inserted" version of the row and the "deleted" version regardless of the table schema and ignoring a specific column (because if rowversion get in the operation, the rows will not be the same...). The main goal here is a Single-Script where i just change the table name...

Comment: I think your best bet here is going to be writing a sql script that will take a table and script out the compare for you.  Can then paste that compare into your triggers for the tables.

Comment: Yes, you can `group by` fields and use `count`; adding the `having` clause set to `count(unique_field) >=2` will show you duplicates.  Though, table schema matters as you won't be able to take the same query and use it on a different table.  What you're asking for is a `SELECT ALL EXCEPT <fieldset> FROM ...` syntax, which I've been asking for ISO-SQL to adopt for many years.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script I just whipped up that will create a function that you can call from inside your trigger to get a compare query.  You can then run that query and insert the results into a temp table and you do whatever you need to do based on whether the row changed or not.

```
create function GetChangedRowsQuery(
    @TableName              varchar(50), 
    @PrimaryKeyColumnName   varchar(50),
    @RowVersionColumnName   varchar(50) = ''
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

    declare 
        @ColumnName varchar(50),
        @GetChangedRowsQuery varchar(max)

    select @GetChangedRowsQuery = 
    'select isnull(a.' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + ', b.' + + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + ') 
       from #inserted a
       full join #deleted b on a.' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + ' = b.' + @PrimaryKeyColumnName + '
      where '

    declare ColumnCursor cursor Read_Only
    for select Name
          from Sys.columns
         where object_id = Object_Id('Member')

    open ColumnCursor
    fetch next from ColumnCursor into @ColumnName
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      begin

        if (@ColumnName != @PrimaryKeyColumnName and @ColumnName != @RowVersionColumnName)
          begin
            select @GetChangedRowsQuery = @GetChangedRowsQuery + '((a.' + @ColumnName + ' != b.' + @ColumnName + ' or a.' + @ColumnName + ' is null or b.' + @ColumnName + ' is null) and (a.' + @ColumnName + ' is not null or b.' + @ColumnName + ' is not null))' + char(13) + '      or ' 
          end
        fetch next from ColumnCursor into @ColumnName
      end

    close ColumnCursor
    deallocate ColumnCursor

    select @GetChangedRowsQuery = substring(@GetChangedRowsQuery, 0, len(@GetChangedRowsQuery) -7)

    return @GetChangedRowsQuery
end
```

Then you can create your trigger to look like this

```
create trigger TestTrigger on Member for Insert, Update, Delete
as
begin

    //We can't access the inserted or deleted tables from inside the exec statement
    //Dump that data into temp tables so you we can
    select *
      into #Inserted
      from Inserted

    select *
      into #Deleted
      from Deleted

    declare @GetChangedRowsQuery varchar(max)

    select @GetChangedRowsQuery = dbo.GetChangedRowsQuery('Member', 'MemberId', '')

    select @GetChangedRowsQuery

    create table #Temp (PrimaryKey int)

    insert into #Temp (PrimaryKey)
    exec (@GetChangedRowsQuery) 

    //Do what you need to do with the rows that have or haven't been updated

    drop table #Temp

end
go
```

I've updated this answer about a dozen times now, and I think I've worked the bugs out, but I make no guarantees.

A query like this could be crushing to performance, and I'm not sure I'd actually recommend implementing it, but it was fun to create.